# Substract and divide color image with r,g,b pairs in python Opencv

Tags: opencv, python

How can I substract a r,g,b values from image in cv2?
Then I like to divide with another r,g,b values.

Say I have an color image Img.
Img = (Img - (r,g,b))/(r,g,b)

Actually this is image normalization implementation with own r,g,b values.

How can I do in opencv python, cv2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand, but I think you want:

```
# red channel = (red channel - r) / r
im[...,0] = (im[...,0] - r) / r

# green channel = (green channel - g) / g
im[...,1]= (im[...,1] - g) / g

# blue channel = (blue channel - b) / b
im[...,2] = (im[...,2] - b) / b
```

You may need/want to convert to `float` first to avoid truncation, rounding, clipping, i.e.:

```
im = im.astype(np.float)
```

Answer (score 0):

First read desired image

```
import cv2  
image = cv2.imread('yourimage.jpg')

# You can convert the color space if you prefer. Example-
# image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Extracting colors and modifying

```
# If read image as default, c1, c2, c3 are probably B, G, and R
c1, c2, c3 = image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2]

# Do color modifications as you like
c1 = (c1 - 20) / 20
```

Create/Save new image with modified color changes

```
# Using original image copy because I don't know how to create `numpy.ndarray manually
im2 = image.copy()    
im2[:,:,0], im2[:,:,1], im2[:,:,2] = c1, c2, c3

# Save your new image, remember this method also expects
# image in BGR format I believe.
cv2.imwrite('newimage.jpg', im2)
```